# tabula.read_pdf erro ao executar

Tags: python

Quando executo o código segunte código:

```
import tabula

lista_tabelas = tabula.read_pdf ("FORMULARIO.pdf", pages="all")
print(len(lista_tabelas),)
```

está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

```
C:\PDF\lerPDF\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\u0170660\PycharmProjects\lerPDF\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u0170660\PycharmProjects\lerPDF\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    lista_tabelas = tabula.read_pdf ("FORMULARIO.pdf", pages="all")
  File "C:\PDF\lerPDF\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 440, in read_pdf
    raw_json: List[Any] = json.loads(output.decode(encoding))
  File "C:\Users\u0170660\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\u0170660\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\u0170660\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 6 (char 5)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

O Java está instalado corretamente, já desinstalei o tabula e instalei novamente e ainda persiste.

Por gentileza, conseguem me ajudar com essa dúvida?

Abs,

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Olá, preciso que o código retorno a quantidade de tabelas no arquivo PDF

Comment: Tem uma amostragem do csv para teste? Parece ser problema com o delimitador.

Answer (score -3):

Tente usar o método naativo de python, ficaria algo como

```
 with open("file_path", "rb") as file:
        read = file.readline()
```

Comment: c0d3r-lcs, obrigado por ajudar. Tentei mas não retornou os dados do arquivo PDF

Answer (score -3):

hmmm certo... Olha nao sei qual tipo de processo você está querendo fazer mas aqui vai outra funçao que pode ajudar...

Desta formar você teria um binário como retorno, esse tipo de dado pode ser útil para trafegar em protocolo http e até mesmo salvar em banco de dados ou até converter para base64

```
with open("file_path", "rb") as file:
        read = file.readline()
```

Já essta função vai ler o pdf e retornar o texto como string (usando a lib PyPDF2)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def pdf_to_text(file_name: str) -> str:
    r = open(file_name, "rb")
    pdf_read = PdfFileReader(r)
    page = pdf_read.getPage(0)
    txt = page.extractText()
    return str(txt)
```

Tente a segunda opção e me avise se deu tudo certo, caso não me conte mais detalhadamente sobre meu problema.